# nginx takes a long time to start and stub_status takes more than 9s too

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04

My nginx setup works perfectly fine and responds fast to all my requests, but I noticed recently that nginx takes a long time to start (>30s) and the endpoint that I configured to serve the `stub_status` directive takes >9s also, causing the telegraf daemon nginx plugin to timeout.

What could be taking such a long amount of time?

Note: I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thousands of `server` blocks?

Comment: No, I have no more than 10 `server` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by outdated nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Once the nameservers were replaced, nginx restarted super fast.